# Different JBOSS versions (5.1 and 7.1.1) same Port

Tags: port, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

i´ve got a problem i have two files a WAR and an EAR file. The EAR file will be deployed with JBOSS 5.1 and the WAR file wit JBOSS 7. But it doesnt. I got the following error message:

```
ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:8080
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]

 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector .http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector

at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]

Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
    ... 5 more
```

Can you help me? Can i change the port in any xml file?

Greetz Marko

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change JBoss 5 ports:

Edit server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml and change `<parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-default}</parameter>`   to `<parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}</parameter>`

This will add an offset of 100 to port numbers. For example, 8080 will become 8180.

For jboss 7, edit standalone.xml, look for

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
```

and change the 0 for the offset you want to add.. For example,

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
```

will turn 8080 to 8180